# Not doing CG drawings correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics

Just started working with Core Graphics and I probably got no idea what's going on.

In the following code I'm trying to create a small rounded translucent black square overlaid on top of the **UINavigationController**, but so far nothing showed up...

```
UIView *notificationView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[[self navigationController] view] frame]];

CGRect rect = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width / 2 - 50, self.view.frame.size.height / 2, 100, 100);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, NO, 0.0);
[[UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0.5] setFill];

UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:rect cornerRadius:10];
[path fill];

[notificationView setNeedsDisplay];

[[[self navigationController] view] addSubview:notificationView];
```

Comment: This code will fail anywhere outside of `drawRect` because `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()` will return `nil`.  Look into `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions`

Comment: OK I updated the code, still not showing anything :/

Comment: You really need to better understand how all of this stuff works. I said "look into" it, not "just paste it in there".  This will draw into an image buffer (but you still need to do something with it).  However, I see that you want it to display to the screen.  If you want to draw into the navigation controller itself, you will need to subclass it and override its `drawRect` method.  *Only* inside that method will `UIGraphicsGetImageContext()` return non-`nil` (and you don't need to begin an image context there).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1** (the most design-friendly one)

`UIView`s are not really meant for other objects to draw into them. It makes much more design sense to subclass `UIView` and let it do its own drawing in `drawRect`. That way, you don't have to paste so much code every time you want to use a notification view.

**Option 2** (the easiest one, and probably best)

If you just want a translucent black rounded rectangle (I'm assuming for a loading indicator), you can do it much more easily by creating the UIView at the size you want and centering it in the view. Set its background color to the translucent color, `[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.5]`. Finally, add the line

```
notificationView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0;
```

You may also need to put `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` in your header file, since this is a `CALayer` trick.

**Option 3** (the roundabout one)

If you really want to do it the way you're already doing, change the `notificationView` to a `UIImageView`, then set the frame of the view to be the size of the black rounded rect. Then add this after you fill the path:

```
UIImage *indicatorImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
notificationView.image = indicatorImage;
```

You don't need to call `setNeedsDisplay` anymore.

Hopefully one of these sounds good to you!

Comment: I came back to my code a few hours later and realized I really should have subclassed it, but option 2 sounds awesome too so I'll take that one :D thank!